# C# Logging User Actions - Best Method?

Tags: c#, windows-7

I would like to record the actions of a user when they are using the base Operating System with my application open.

For example, Clicked Start, Clicked All Programs, Clicked Microsoft Office, Clicked Microsoft Word....

Can anyone suggest a sensible method to achieve this?

*The idea is that the user's actions are only recorded when my application is open, its meant to be an alternative to the Microsoft recorder. It creates a written procedure that can be sent to a customer service department.*

Comment: Sounds a bit Orwellian. What is your reasoning?

Comment: There already exist such "big brother" programs ... or is the goal to  *create* such a program from scratch?

Comment: The aim is to get a script that can be used by a customer service department to re-create an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should ask yourself if your users will appreciate this! Maybe they care about their privacy.
Anyway you can do it using [hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (I think you're writing for Windows). Same task as a macro recorder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do that, why not just use an existing program. We used [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) at my last job to do this for creating UI testing code.

You could ask the user to install AutoHotkey and have them record the script. It can then be sent to you. You can run the script yourself (although you may have to tweak the screen resolution and things like that), and see what was happening.

EDIT:
<strike>Another idea is have the user record a screen cast and send that to you. It might make it easier to debug.</strike>
I didn't know what Microsoft Recorder was, thought it was the sound recorder, didn't realize there is a Microsoft Problem Recorder bundled in Win7, which does the whole screen cast recording.